# Retain Embedded Cover Images Between ffmpeg Conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I like to embed a cover image into my video files, but I have noticed that they are lost whenever I convert or remux, is there a way to retain these embedded images like I can with metadata? Are there limitations to this depending on which container I use? The code below is for converting the video stream to AV1, and keeps the original infile container. Most of the time the container I am using is Matroska Video.

```
for %%f in (%*) do (ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i %%f -movflags use_metadata_tags -c:v libsvtav1 -preset %Preset% -crf %CRF% -b:v %ABR%M -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~nf (AV1)%%~xf")
```